# Testing advantage with dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

I recently started learning Spring and the concept of dependency injection. I have some knowledge of **Junit** testing and **Mocking** concepts but still haven't been able to wrap my head around the specific testing-related advantage that dependency injection offers.

For example I instantiate class Triangle the following way :-

```
Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();
```

and now with dependency injection using Spring , I do it the following way

```
Triangle triangle2 = (Triangle) beanFactory.getBean("triangle");
```

Say the `Triangle` class has some methods that need testing. What would be the different approaches in testing `triangle1` and `triangle2`

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection. Then you can still just use `new` in your unit tests, providing mocks for the dependencies.

Comment: And even if you were going to use `getBean` (1. use constructor injection, 2. autowire into your test class), use the generic signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring you don't explicitly lookup the bean from the factory. Instead the container initializes the beans before you use them, so your code doesn't have to invoke the container itself.

It's common in a web application to have web controllers that handle converting web requests and posts into calls to business logic, services that handle implementing business logic transactionally, and data access objects with methods that each perform a simple query or update. (All these are normally stateless, the only instance members are references to other stateless objects, and they can execute multiple requests concurrently.) The objects in each layer depend on those in the next lower layer, and Spring wires all these objects together on startup.

If I have a controller that uses a service, Spring creates the controller and the service and wires the service into the controller. Application code never calls the bean factory.

```
public class SomeWebController {
    private MyBusinessLogicService  myBusinessLogicService;

    public SomeWebController(MyBusinessLogicService myBusinessLogicService) {
        this.myBusinessLogicService = myBusinessLogicService;
    }
    ...
}
```

The unit test doesn't have to know about the container. The test can setup the object being tested by plugging in mocks for its dependencies, either by creating those dependencies and calling setter methods directly or by creating a test configuration and having that plug in the mocks.

If I have a controller that doesn't use Spring, and it instantiates the service directly using its constructor, then it's harder to substitute a mock for the service. I would have to do something like refactor to introduce a factory method for the service and in the test override it to return a mock. This would introduce boilerplate code in the tests where I had to subclass the class I was testing, and I'd have gaps in my coverage where the overridden factory methods weren't exercised.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So when I test the 2nd case in my original post, I would write something like the following :

`Triangle tester = Mockito.mock(Triangle.class);`

Cant I write the same thing for my first case? How does being agnostic to the container put me in an advantageous situation?

Comment: @user3559089; a more fleshed-out example would help. Spring is for wiring things together, when you only have a single object as an example it's hard to see what the issue is.

Comment: Can you give me a fleshed out example? I wouldn't know what kind of an example you are thinking about... Thanks!